# External OAuth authentication with Nginx in Kubernetes

Tags: nginx, kubernetes

Having trouble setting up external authentication for a web application behind nginx ingress. When i try to access the URL https://site.example.com from external i get no redirection to Github login, and direct access to web application happens.

Running Pods for my environment:

```
NAME                              READY   STATUS   
nginx-ingress-68df4dfc4f-wpj5t    1/1     Running  
oauth2-proxy-6675d4b57c-cspw8     1/1     Running   
web-deployment-7d4bd85b46-blxb8   1/1     Running   
web-deployment-7d4bd85b46-nqjgl   1/1     Running
```

Active Services:

```
NAME            TYPE           CLUSTER-IP       EXTERNAL-IP    PORT(S)                      
nginx-ingress   LoadBalancer   10.96.156.157    192.168.1.82   80:31613/TCP,443:32437/TCP   
oauth2-proxy    ClusterIP      10.100.101.251   <none>         4180/TCP                     
web-service     ClusterIP      10.108.237.188   <none>         8080/TCP
```

Two Ingress resources:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: ingress
  namespace: nginx-ingress
  annotations:
     kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
     nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/auth-url: "https://$host/oauth2/auth"
     nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/auth-signin: "https://$host/oauth2/start?rd=$request_uri"
  labels:
    app: webapp
spec:
  rules:
  - host: site.example.com
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        backend:
          serviceName: web-service
          servicePort: 8080
  tls:
  - hosts:
    - site.example.com
    secretName: example-tls
```

---

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: oauth2-proxy
  namespace: nginx-ingress
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
  labels:
    app: oauth2-proxy
spec:
  rules:
  - host: site.example.com
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          serviceName: oauth2-proxy
          servicePort: 4180
        path: /oauth2

  tls:
  - hosts:
    - site.example.com
    secretName: example-tls
```

Ingress output:

```
NAME           CLASS    HOSTS              ADDRESS        PORTS     
ingress        <none>   site.example.com   192.168.1.82   80, 443   
oauth2-proxy   <none>   site.example.com                  80, 443
```

I see these errors in Ingress oauth2-proxy events:

```
Events:
  Type     Reason    Age   From                      Message
  ----     ------    ----  ----                      -------
  Warning  Rejected  54m   nginx-ingress-controller  All hosts are taken by other resources
```

Oauth2-proxy built from deployment [here](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/master/docs/examples/auth/oauth-external-auth/oauth2-proxy.yaml) with Client ID, Client Secret and SECRET according to the OAuth app created in my Github account.

No logs found in oauth2-proxy logs, i suppose because it's not invoked in the process.

**UPDATE**:

This question was incomplete, i forgot to mention the NGINX image empolyed (NGINX 1.9.0 from [installation guide](https://docs.nginx.com/nginx-ingress-controller/installation/installation-with-manifests/)).

Changing the image with the below:

```
NGINX Ingress controller
Release: v0.41.2
Build: d8a93551e6e5798fc4af3eb910cef62ecddc8938
Repository: https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx
nginx version: nginx/1.19.4
```

the error disappears. In brief both Ingress configuration, the one from my question and the other from the answer are working.

Comment: Based on external IP it's your local env. Are you using `Kubeadm` or `Minikube`? Its one machine or you have some virtualization software like `VMVare` or `VirtualBox`? You are using newest k8s and nginx-ingress-controller v0.9.0 or greatetr? You didnt use any other apps like `Let's encrypt`?

Comment: Kubeadm - Virtualbox - nginx-ingress:1.9.0 and newest k8s, i'm using certifcate signed locally with openssl

Comment: Kubeadm v1.19.3, cluster of Master and 2 worker

Answer (score 2):

In your configuration, you are using 2 [Ingress](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/). As you described you `oauth2-proxy Ingress`, in `Event` section you can find information:

> All hosts are taken by other resources

Issue you have encounter here is called [Host Collisions](https://docs.nginx.com/nginx-ingress-controller/configuration/handling-host-collisions/). It occured as in your both `Ingress` you have used:

```
spec:
  rules:
  - host: site.example.com
```

In that kind of situation, `Ingress` is using default algorith called [Choosing the Winner](https://docs.nginx.com/nginx-ingress-controller/configuration/handling-host-collisions/#choosing-the-winner).

> If multiple resources contend for the same host, the `Ingress Controller` will pick the winner based on the `creationTimestamp` of the resources: the oldest resource will win.

As fast solution for your issue is to create one `Ingress` with 2 paths.

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: ingress
  namespace: nginx-ingress
  annotations:
     kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
     nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/auth-url: "https://$host/oauth2/auth"
     nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/auth-signin: "https://$host/oauth2/start?rd=$request_uri"
spec:
  rules:
  - host: site.example.com
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        backend:
          serviceName: web-service
          servicePort: 8080
      - path: /oauth2
        backend:
          serviceName: oauth2-proxy
          servicePort: 4180      
  tls:
  - hosts:
    - site.example.com
    secretName: example-tls
```

Another way to resolve this issue is to use [Merging Configuration for the Same Host](https://docs.nginx.com/nginx-ingress-controller/configuration/handling-host-collisions/#merging-configuration-for-the-same-host), however it shouldn't be applied in this scenario.

As last thing, you can follow official Nginx Ingress tutorial - [External OAUTH Authentication](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/examples/auth/oauth-external-auth/)

Comment: Thanks for reply. The result with Ingress provided with two paths: if i type https://site.example.com i get directly to the web app without authentication, if i type the same URL with /oauth2 i get redirected to the Github login page. I would expect authentication when URL https://site.example.com is typed.

Comment: To achieve that you just need change path, for `web-service` path from `/` change to `/web` and for `oauth2-proxy` change path from `/oauth2` to `/`. That way you will be redirected to login page when you will enter `site.example.com`

Comment: Fine. Accessing https://site.example.com now redirects to Github login, after entering user\password i got 500Internal Server Error, inspecting oauth2-proxy logs i can find this: Error redeeming code during OAuth2 callback: error performing request: Post "https://github.com/login/oauth/access_token": dial tcp: lookup github.com on 10.96.0.10:53: server misbehaving. Getting /bin/sh into oauth2-proxy and executing nslookup github.com cannot be resolved, i think it's a DNS issue so oauth2-proxy cannot resolve github.com

Comment: The DNS issue was related to /etc/resolv.conf in worker nodes, editing the file with correct nameserver now the OAuth2 is successful. After authentication the browser is redirected to https://site.example.com  with 404 page not found

Comment: @Marco_81 Main question here was that you was not redirected to authenticated pod which root cause of the issue was ingress configuration. With Oauth issue, according to StackOverflow guidelines, you should create new question. It would be good if you could provide how did you configured oauth and add oauth tag

Comment: Yes i should open a new question and provide more OAuth information. Before accepting your answer as solved however i would be sure the Ingress conf. you provided would work 100%. Do you agree?

Comment: Please let me know if the correct way is to post OAuth information in this question. regards

Comment: I've followed tutorial from `Ingress` and it worked for me if you are asking about Ingress configuration. According to SO rules, each question should be asked separately, not mixing multiple questions in one.

Comment: Posted new question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64776399/nginx-ingress-with-oauth2-authentication-404-page-not-found-in-kubernetes).