# Nginx Ingress with OAuth2 authentication 404 page not found in Kubernetes

Tags: nginx, kubernetes, oauth-2.0

following the previous question on Stack Overflow at this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64590283/external-oauth-authentication-with-nginx-in-kubernetes), after successful authentication (at Github.com) i get *404 page not found* on my browser.

The Ingress configuration below (used by nginx-ingress controller):

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: ingress
  namespace: nginx-ingress
  annotations:
     nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/auth-url: "https://$host/oauth2/auth"
     nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/auth-signin: "https://$host/oauth2/start?rd=$request_uri"
spec:
  ingressClassName: nginx
  rules:
  - host: site.example.com
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /v1                                               
        backend:
          serviceName: web-service
          servicePort: 8080
      - path: /
        backend:
          serviceName: oauth2-proxy
          servicePort: 4180
  tls:
  - hosts:
    - site.example.com
    secretName: example-tls
```

---

```
$ kubectl get ing -n nginx-ingress
  NAME      CLASS   HOSTS              ADDRESS   PORTS     
  ingress   nginx   site.example.com             80, 443
```

- browser sends GET to https://site.example.com/,
- browser is redirected to Github login page,
- After successful login, browser is redirected to https://site.example.com/,
- browser sends GET to https://site.example.com/ with cookie _oauth2_proxy filled
- the response is *404 page not found*

The node.js web application i'm trying to access to via oauth2 has been built with two paths (/ and /v1). Web application is behind Service *web-service*.

OAuth2 Github application configuration:

```
Homepage URL
https://site.example.com/

Authorization callback URL
https://site.example.com/oauth2/callback
```

OAuth2 deployment and service:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  labels:
    k8s-app: oauth2-proxy
  name: oauth2-proxy
  namespace: nginx-ingress
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      k8s-app: oauth2-proxy
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        k8s-app: oauth2-proxy
    spec:
      containers:
      - args:
        - --provider=github
        - --email-domain=*
        - --upstream=file:///dev/null
        - --http-address=0.0.0.0:4180
        # Register a new application
        # https://github.com/settings/applications/new
        env:
        - name: OAUTH2_PROXY_CLIENT_ID
          value: 32066******52
        - name: OAUTH2_PROXY_CLIENT_SECRET
          value: ff2b0a***************9bd
        - name: OAUTH2_PROXY_COOKIE_SECRET
          value: deSF_t******03-HQ==
        image: quay.io/oauth2-proxy/oauth2-proxy:latest
        imagePullPolicy: Always
        name: oauth2-proxy
        ports:
        - containerPort: 4180
          protocol: TCP
```

---

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  labels:
    k8s-app: oauth2-proxy
  name: oauth2-proxy
  namespace: nginx-ingress
spec:
  ports:
  - name: http
    port: 4180
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 4180
  selector:
    k8s-app: oauth2-proxy
```

Logs from oauth2-proxy container:

```
[2020/11/10 19:47:27] [logger.go:508] Error loading cookied session: cookie "_oauth2_proxy" not present, removing session
10.44.0.2:51854 - - [2020/11/10 19:47:27] site.example.com GET - "/" HTTP/1.1 "Mozilla/5.0
[2020/11/10 19:47:27] [logger.go:508] Error loading cookied session: cookie "_oauth2_proxy" not present, removing session
10.44.0.2:51858 - - [2020/11/10 19:47:27] site.example.com GET - "/favicon.ico" HTTP/1.1 "Mozilla/5.0 ....
10.44.0.2:51864 - - [2020/11/10 19:47:28] site.example.com GET - "/oauth2/start?rd=%2F" HTTP/1.1 "Mozilla/5.0 ....
10.44.0.2:52004 - marco.***81@gmail.com [2020/11/10 19:48:33] [AuthSuccess] Authenticated via OAuth2: Session{email:marco.***81@gmail.com user:mafi81 PreferredUsername: token:true created:2020-11-10 19:48:32.494549621 +0000 UTC m=+137.822819581}
10.44.0.2:52004 - - [2020/11/10 19:48:32] site.example.com GET - "/oauth2/callback?code=da9c3af9d8f35728d2d1&state=e3280edf2430c507cd74f3d4655500c1%3A%2F" HTTP/1.1 "Mozilla/5.0 ...
10.44.0.2:52012 - marco.****81@gmail.com [2020/11/10 19:48:33] site.example.com GET - "/" HTTP/1.1 "Mozilla/5.0 ....
10.44.0.2:52014 - marco.****81@gmail.com [2020/11/10 19:48:33] site.example.com GET - "/favicon.ico" HTTP/1.1 "Mozilla/5.0 .... Chrome/86.0.4240.193 Safari/537.36" 404 19 0.000
```

Testing environment:

- VirtualBox with kubeadm v1.19.3
- NGINX Ingress controller Version=1.9.0.

I'm not still confident with paths configuration under Ingress resource.
Any suggestion on how to go ahead with troubleshoot would be great.

**UPDATE**:

Following the Matt's answer, giving the right way to test the authentication, here is the new environment:

```
NGINX Ingress controller
  Release:       v0.41.2
  Build:         d8a93551e6e5798fc4af3eb910cef62ecddc8938
  Repository:    https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx
  nginx version: nginx/1.19.4

OAuth2 Pod
  image: quay.io/oauth2-proxy/oauth2-proxy
```

Ingress manifest:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: ingress
  namespace: web
  annotations:
     nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/auth-response-headers: Authorization
     nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/auth-url: http://oauth2-proxy.web.svc.cluster.local:4180/oauth2/auth
     nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/auth-signin: https://site.example.com/oauth2/start?rd=$request_uri
     nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/configuration-snippet: |
       auth_request_set $name_upstream_1 $upstream_cookie__oauth2_proxy_1;

       access_by_lua_block {
         if ngx.var.name_upstream_1 ~= "" then
           ngx.header["Set-Cookie"] = "_oauth2_proxy_1=" ..  ngx.var.name_upstream_1 .. ngx.var.auth_cookie:match("(; .*)")
         end
       }

spec:
  ingressClassName: nginx-oauth
  rules:
  - host: site.example.com
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        backend:
          serviceName: web-service
          servicePort: 8080
```

---

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: oauth2-proxy
  namespace: web

spec:
  ingressClassName: nginx-oauth

  rules:
  - host: site.example.com
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          serviceName: oauth2-proxy
          servicePort: 4180
        path: /oauth2

  tls:
  - hosts:
    - site.example.com
    secretName: tls
```

Note that i had to change one annotation to get it working:

- auth-url: http://oauth2- proxy.web.svc.cluster.local:4180/oauth2/auth  (this solves resolution failure)

Comment: You elided the status code from A LOT of the responses, but seeing your email address in the response logs makes it seem as though all the auth dance happened successfully; if you navigate to `site.example.com/v1/whatever` I would expect you would be permitted without having to auth again (assuming the cookie is successfully provided, of course)

Comment: Separately, while this isn't what you asked, using a docker tag of `:latest` on a project you don't control is asking for very, very, very weird bugs to start to show up. That project specifically overhauled itself a few times from v5 to v6, which your cluster will silently update on pull

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [oauth-proxy documentation](https://oauth2-proxy.github.io/oauth2-proxy/docs/configuration/overview#configuring-for-use-with-the-nginx-auth_request-directive) you MUST use [kubernetes/ingress-nginx](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/deploy/).

Here you can read more about [differences between nginxinc/kubernetes-ingress and kubernetes/ingress-nginx Ingress Controllers](https://github.com/nginxinc/kubernetes-ingress/blob/master/docs/nginx-ingress-controllers.md).

In oath2-proxy docs (mentioned earlier) you can find the following:

> When you use ingress-nginx in Kubernetes, you MUST use kubernetes/ingress-nginx (which includes the Lua module) and the following configuration snippet for your Ingress. Variables set with auth_request_set are not set-able in plain nginx config when the location is processed via proxy_pass and then may only be processed by Lua. Note that nginxinc/kubernetes-ingress does not include the Lua module.
>
> ```
> nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/auth-response-headers: Authorization
> nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/auth-signin: https://$host/oauth2/start?rd=$escaped_request_uri
> nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/auth-url: https://$host/oauth2/auth
> nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/configuration-snippet: |
>   auth_request_set $name_upstream_1 $upstream_cookie_name_1;
>
>   access_by_lua_block {
>     if ngx.var.name_upstream_1 ~= "" then
>       ngx.header["Set-Cookie"] = "name_1=" .. ngx.var.name_upstream_1 .. ngx.var.auth_cookie:match("(; .*)")
>     end
>   }
> ```

So if we can trust documentation, your authentication won't work because you are using wrong nginx controller and you are missing annotations.

Comment: Yes it works! with some adjustment, going to UPDATE. thanks Matt